# Primefaces dialog continuously moves right and left when adding some values to inputText

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces, xhtml

I'm designing a web page with primefaces 3.5 and java 8.

This xhtml page has a dialog which opens when the user press a certain button. This dialog include javascript which is about geolocation and auto fill. Some input text filled according to this function like Adress Line 1 etc and others filled by user like Adress Line 2 etc.

My problem is, when user finish geolocation operation and try to fill manual fields dialog continuously moves right and left. It is like dialog trying to stay where it is.

I'm not sharing whole page. There were many fields that were manually filled so I deleted them in order to avoid confusion, but I just left the address line 2. I did not delete the auto filled fields. You can see code below.

```
<p:dialog id="addressDialog"
            onShow="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.addressAdd}"
            widgetVar="addressDialogWidget" modal="true" header="Ship To Address"
            closable="false"
            rendered="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.customer.addressCreationGrant}"
            resizable="false"
            width="400"
            style="max-height:700px; overflow:auto">
            <p:messages id="addressMessages" autoUpdate="true"></p:messages>
            
            
<style type="text/css">
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        text-transform: initial;
    }
    
    :-moz-placeholder { 
       text-transform: initial;
    }
    
    ::-moz-placeholder {  
       text-transform: initial;
    }
    
    :-ms-input-placeholder { 
       text-transform: initial;
    }
    
    .pac-item {
    white-space:normal !important;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name',
    political: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: []});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value;
    
    $(document).on("change", ".pac-target-input", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
    });
    
  }
  
  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("addressForm:cua2").value = "";
    for (var component in componentForm) {
        
      if(!component && !document.getElementById(component)){
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      } 
     
    }
    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[j];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) 
          {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
           
            if (addressType == "locality") 
            {
                document.getElementById("addressForm:town").value = val;
            }
            else if (addressType == "street_number" || addressType == "route" || addressType == "neighborhood") 
            {
                if (val.length != 0){
                    if(document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value.length != 0) {
                        document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value = document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value.trim() + " " + val;
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value = val;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (addressType == "country") 
            {
                if(val.toUpperCase() === "CANADA")
                {
                    countryCode.selectValue("CA");
                    document.getElementById("cscdInput").value = "CA";
                }
                else if(val.toUpperCase() === "UNITED STATES")
                {
                    countryCode.selectValue("US");
                    document.getElementById("cscdInput").value = "US";
                }
             }
            else if (addressType == "postal_code") 
            {
                document.getElementById("addressForm:postal_code").value = val;
                document.getElementById("opponoInput").value = val;
            }
            else if (addressType == "administrative_area_level_1") 
            {
                stateProvince.selectValue(val);
                document.getElementById("stateInput").value = val;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      document.getElementById('autocomplete').value = document.getElementById("addressForm:cua1").value;
    }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  
  function getAllCodes(){
      stateProvince.selectValue(document.getElementById("stateInput").value);
      document.getElementById("addressForm:postal_code").value = document.getElementById("opponoInput").value;
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOHX1eQCUKHqsNmzArqsSmagr5_uesIVE&amp;libraries=places&amp;callback=initAutocomplete"
>
</script>
            
            <div style="width: 350px;margin: 0 auto;">
                
                <div style="width: 235px; margin: 0 auto;">
                    
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px; display:none">
                        <p:inputText maxlength="29" style="text-transform:capitalize;" id="cua1"
                            value="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.addressBean.OPCUA1}"></p:inputText>
                        <p:watermark value="*Address Line 1" for="cua1"></p:watermark>
                    </div>


                    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <p:inputText maxlength="29" style="text-transform:capitalize;" id="cua2" disabled="false"
                            value="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.addressBean.OPCUA2}"></p:inputText>
                        <p:watermark value="Address Line 2" for="cua2"></p:watermark>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="cscd" widgetVar="countryCode"
                            value="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.addressBean.OPCSCD}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="*Country" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.countryCodes}"></f:selectItems>
                            <p:ajax
                                listener="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.countryChangedListener}" oncomplete="getAllCodes()"
                                update="ecarGroup ponoGroup" process="cscd"></p:ajax>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <h:panelGroup id="ecarGroup" >
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="ecar" widgetVar="stateProvince"
                                value="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.addressBean.OPECAR}">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue=""
                                    itemLabel="*State/Province" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{managedBeanForPlaceOrder.stateCodes}"></f:selectItems>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#addressForm\\:ecar').on('click', function(e){
                                if($('#addressForm\\:cscd_label').text() == 'Country')
                                {
                                     $('#addressForm\\:ecar_panel').hide();
                                      $('#addressForm\\:addressMessages').html(
                                          
                                          "<div class=\"ui-messages-error ui-corner-all\">" +
                                           "<span class=\"ui-messages-error-icon\">" + 
                                          "</span><ul><li>" + 
                                          "<span class=\"ui-messages-error-summary\">" +
                                            "Please first select country.</span></li>" +
                                          "</ul></div>"
                                        
                                        );
                                }
                            });
                            
                            </script>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is way too much code and no version info.

Comment: Hello Jasper, I edited question according to your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: So it works when you take out `<div style="width: 350px;margin: 0 auto;">`?